# az cli select first value of an object

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface

The `az webapp identity show` command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-identity-show

Will return the following result:

```
{
  "principalId": null,
  "tenantId": null,
  "type": "UserAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": {
    "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx": {
      "clientId": "xxx",
      "principalId": "xxx"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am only intrested in returning the `/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` value. How can I filter this value using `--query` option? I have tried

```
--query userAssignedIdentities

        "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx": {
          "clientId": "xxx",
          "principalId": "xxx"
        }
      }
```

But there is something more required to get the first key here. What?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below Azure CLI cmdlet

```
az webapp identity show -name <WebAppName> -g <ResoureGroupName> --query  "keys(userAssignedIdentities)" -o tsv
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the below PowerShell cmdlet to pull the resourceId of the userAssignedIdentities that is assigned to Azure web app.

```
$identity=Get-AzWebApp -Name <WebAppName> -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" | select -ExpandProperty Identity
$identity.UserAssignedIdentities.Keys
```

[image]